# Strange behaviour, results from linked DB

Tags: oracle, toad, dblink

Running this query on Toad

```
select * from customer@linkedDb 
where "CustomerNumber"=1
```

Gets a single row results, however

```
select * from customer@linkedDb 
where "CustomerNumber"=(select 1 from dual)
```

Still returns a single row, but almost every column is NULL
Any data-conversion functions or links to other tables cause this same effect.  Any ideas?

Trying this on SQL+, I get this:

```
select "Forename" from customer@linkedDb where "CustomerNumber"=1
```

Result: Amy

```
select "Forename" from customer@linkedDb where "CustomerNumber"=(select 1 from dual)
```

Result: A m y

I am sure this must be some character encoding thing, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run the above two queries in SQL*Plus?

Comment: Sorry you are right - it is not a toad issue.
SQL+ also does not return what I need (I have updated the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is converting from nvarchar to varchar...

```
Select 
 Cast("Forename" As Varchar(50))
From
 customer@linkedDb
Where
 "CustomerNumber"=(select 1 from dual)
```

Doesn't work, because the (select 1 from dual) seems to cause the data to be autocast.  What does work is any alteration to the value after casting - which I *think* may be prompting Oracle to change the order of things

```
Select 
 Substr(Cast("Forename" As Varchar(50)),1,50)
From
 customer@linkedDb
Where
 "CustomerNumber"=(select 1 from dual)
```

This works.  It is an ugly - slightly expensive solution, so I have some workarounds in place - but I thought I would post this as food for thought if anyone else comes across the same problem.